# I had/have never thought about until now

Tags: past-tense, grammaticality-in-context

Someone asked me why I want to get a high score on  my test. I said the following:
*"I had never thought about it until now."*

I'm a bit confused between 'I had' and 'I have' since I said 'now' at the end. I know that we say things like "I had never met her until last night/recently" but 'now' doesn't sound like past to me.
Which one is correct here?

Comment: Why does anyone need to ask you why you want to get a high score on a test? Doesn't everyone who takes a test want a high score?

Comment: We were talking about IELTS. She said that because most universities require no more than 6.5 and I said I wanted to score an 8 or 9.

Comment: If you can get 8 or 9, and you know it, aim for that. Be the best you can be. Also do that later at university. Don't be mediocre. Be good. Don't be "most", be better than most.

Comment: Also, if you aim for 9 and get 7, you're good. If you aim for 6.5 and get 5.5, you're screwed.

Comment: Your friend sounds foolish.

Answer (score 2):

So, first of all, you are right about the sentence not being in the past.

Because the expression *"until now"* is primarily used with the meaning of "a negative statement describing a situation that *has existed* up to this point or up to the present time", using the present perfect sounds like the correct choice!

Comment: So if I have to end a this kind of sentence with 'now' it should always be 'have' and not 'had?'

Comment: *now, recently, lately*. All are fine.